# Searching for a js drag and drop design editor

Tags: javascript, desktop-publishing

I'm searching for a JavaScript library providing a drag and drop design editor. The user shall be able to create his own design for an event ticket. I'll try to explain what it should do:

At the top, there needs to be a basic toolbar with, let's say, a textbox button and an image button. Below the toolbar, there is a div or something sized like the ticket will be sized. Now the user needs to be able to design the ticket's layout. So he might drag a textbox onto the ticket and insert the event's name, add another textbox with a short description of the event to the ticket, and so on.

Is there something similar already existing? Searching for *js editor* only shows up real code editors.